# problemas con forkJoin para obtener una entidad con propiedades mapeadasde multiples observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Estoy intentando obtener una entidad con propiedades mapeadas de varios observables y hasta aqui va todo bien

```
avalesConPropiedadesMapeadas$ = forkJoin([    
 this.avales$,
 this.tipoAvales$,
 this.estadoAvales$,
 this.avalistas$,
 this.responsables$,
 this.proyectos$
])
.pipe(
 map(([avales, tipoAvales, estadoAvales, avalistas, responsables, proyectos]) =>
  avales.map(aval => ({
    ...aval,
    tipoAval: tipoAvales.find(t => t.id == aval.tipoAvalId).nombre,
    estadoAval: estadoAvales.find(t => t.id == aval.estadoAvalId).nombre,
    avalista: avalistas.find(t => t.id == aval.avalistaId).nombre,
    responsableNombre:responsables.find(r => r.id == aval.responsableId).nombreCompleto,
    clienteId:proyectos.find(p=>p.prjCode==aval.proyectoId)?.u_CardCode,
    clienteNombre:proyectos.find(p=>p.prjCode==aval.proyectoId)?.u_CardName,
    proyectoDescripcion:proyectos.find(p=>p.prjCode==aval.proyectoId)?.u_extname2  
  }) as Aval))
 );
```

Pero ahora necesito otra propiedad mas sacada de otro observable para lo cual añado mi observable de ofertas de donde saco la nueva propiedad al final

```
 avalesConPropiedadesMapeadas$ = forkJoin([    
  this.avales$,
  this.tipoAvales$,
  this.estadoAvales$,
  this.avalistas$,
  this.responsables$,
  this.proyectos$,
  this.oferta$
 ])
.pipe(
 map(([avales, tipoAvales, estadoAvales, avalistas, responsables, proyectos, ofertas]) =>
  avales.map(aval => ({
    ...aval,        
    tipoAval: tipoAvales.find(t => t.id == aval.tipoAvalId).nombre,
    estadoAval: estadoAvales.find(t => t.id == aval.estadoAvalId).nombre,
    avalista: avalistas.find(t => t.id == aval.avalistaId).nombre,
    responsableNombre:responsables.find(r => r.id == aval.responsableId).nombreCompleto,
    clienteId:proyectos.find(p=>p.prjCode==aval.proyectoId)?.u_CardCode,
    clienteNombre:proyectos.find(p=>p.prjCode==aval.proyectoId)?.u_CardName,
    proyectoDescripcion:proyectos.find(p=>p.prjCode==aval.proyectoId)?.u_extname2,
    ofertaDescripcion:ofertas.find(o=>o.id==aval.ofertaId)?.descripcion,
  }) as Aval))
);
```

Pero me salta este error

[image: error]

Aqui dejo un enlace al proyecto en stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-byvfjy?file=src/app/avales/filtro-avales/filtro-avales.component.ts

En el menu Avales>editar se puede ver el listado con los mismos

Alguna idea por favor?

Salu2

Comment: Así a primera vista no veo ningún error de sintaxis. Puedes por favor añadir a la pregunta el tipo con el que tienes marcada (o al que te está resolviendo) la propiedad `oferta$`, así como las interfaces de la oferta y el aval?.

Comment: @akotech he incluido enlace al proyecto en stackblitz por si puede servirte gracias y un saludo

Comment: no consigo reproducir el error que comentas en stackblitz. He añadido las ofertas al `forkJoin` y no me esta dando ningún error en el editor. Me he fijado que el código del stackblitz no es exactamente igual que el que incluyes en la pregunta. Por ejemplo, en la pregunta tienes `proyectos.find(p=>p.prjCode...` y en stackblitz es `proyectos.find(p=>p.id==...`.

Comment: @akotech después de actualizar el proyecto de stackblitz con el mio en local: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-byvfjy?file=src/app/avales/filtro-avales/filtro-avales.component.ts lo que me tiene bloqueado es que como bien dices en stackblitz me funciona y en local me da error. De locos...Puede estar relacionado con la versión de typescript? en stackblitz la es2015 y en local la es2017

Comment: @akotech esto me dice VS Code al compilar cada metodo find Error: src/app/avales/filtro-avales/filtro-avales.component.ts:119:32 - error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type '{ <S extends Proyecto>(predicate: (this: void, value: Proyecto, index: number, obj: Proyecto[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S; (predicate: (value: Proyecto, index: number, obj: Proyecto[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): Proyecto; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; }' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.